# UIButton inside UIScrollview not resizing with UIScrollView even after adding the constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton, autolayout

I am facing a weird issue. I have implemented custom UIButtons as a Tile View in a UIScrollView which is added to superview. It is like there are six buttons, set of two placed sideways, and next set of 2 below them and so on. Now for implementing it to fit all iPhones Screen Sizes, I have added proper constraints to UIScrollView and constraints to UIButton relative to each other and UIScrollView. I have added @2x background  images to each of the button with resolution as 320 *320. I have not provided any heights and widths constraints to them, so that they stretch freely according to different screen sizes.

xib has been initially designed as a 4" screen size. UIScrollView frame is stretching, however button remain positioned as in an iPhone 5S xib, hence it is looking improper on screens like iphone 6 etc.

What is the exact problem here?

Comment: what are the constraints given to the buttons ?

Comment: O trailing constraint from x xis for button 1, 0 relative distance constraint between button1 and button2, 0 leading constraint from x axis right for button2, top constraint for button1 and button2, relative constraints with below set of buttons and so on.

Comment: just use for button 1 0 LEADING not trailing and for button 2 TRAILING

Comment: sorry written that wrong, doing what you told only. also it is working perfectly fine without embedding in UIScrollView

Comment: can you post screenshots of constraints an view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the work done here and confirm if this is correct. I have added constraints required to make the buttons looks proper in all devices.

here is the link

https://github.com/mahesh-agrawal/Test-Buttons-Inside-ScrollView

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. this works perfectly fine. However, I guess I need to ask a few things: While deciding the width of a button relative to another button how do you set it like first item 3.width and second item 4.width?

Comment: i have given equal width from 3 to 4. you can add it by dragging or just select both button and in the pin options there is option for equal width. select that.

Comment: ok. thanks. also how did you give the proportional height constraint? I guess I was missing that only.

Comment: yes ...just assign equal height to any view from any view and then change the multiplier. when you add constraint double click that constraint a new pan will be opened. there in the multiplier put like this. first item.property value:second item.property value. that i have given is 190:568..more clear here...this screenshot describes everything you need to know.  http://screencast.com/t/1BopXJf6DT